# AutoLayouts, Contraints, UIView and re-sizing

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, constraints, autolayout

I have attempted to search for AutoLayout, Contraints and several other items, but I can't seem to find an easy answer to what appears to be a simple issue.  Below are two screenshots.  The first one is a 4" iPhone in Storyboard, the second is the 3.5".

At the bottom, I have a "UIView" that sits on top of all the other layers and will only pop-up when I hit a "share" button.  See my problem?  I want to maintain the same size for the UIView on both the 3.5" and 4".  As you can see, it grows and doesn't look as good on the 4" screen.  What settings need adjusted in order to make this happen.  I know it's going to be a constraint setting.

[image: iPhone 4" in Storyboard.]

[image: iPhone 3.5" in Storyboard]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply select the black top `UIView`, and in the IB window add a height constraint.
To do so, search for "Pin" menu in the bottom right corner of the window, and select "Pin Height".

[image: Xcode Pin Menu]

This tells Xcode that you want your view to always keep the same height. Note that this will probably make one of the previous constraints of your view useless (in my case I deleted the "Top Space" one).

Comment: Wow, how I didn't try that before is beyond me.  Thanks.

Comment: To be fair, I thinks Apple made a terrible UI mistake putting such a important and useful menu just next to the (not so useful) zoom menu.